# Strange problem with DataReader?

Tags: .net, ado.net, odbc, datareader

I am facing a strange issue with DataReader. I am using OdbcClient with a legacy rdbms system.

I am sending follwing command to the database.

```
select Col1, Col2, Col3 from Table1 where Col2 = 'Val1';
```

However in certain cases when I iterate it through DataReader as shown below.

```
IDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();

while(reader.Read())
{
  // Get the values from reader

  int col2 = reader.GetValue(1);

}
```

I get the Col2 value as DBNull inspite of the fact that I have value in the Col2 column in the database. I am getting the values of Col1 and Col3 correctly. What can be the possible reasons of this behaviour?

**Update** : This is fixed if I call cmd.Prepare() before calling cmd.ExecuteQuery(). Please  can anyone explain this behaviour?

Comment: Check your spelling near Col2 = 'Val1;

Comment: What happens when you load data into a DataTable? `table.Load(reader)`

Answer (score 0):

What is the data type of Col2? you are reading with GetValue, and maybe the database has a value that is not convertible to Int... is it the case?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to read with named argument:

```
int col2 = int.parse(reader["Col2"].ToString());
```

?